# Gnuplot negative x range and logscale

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot some data with Gnuplot and would like to use a logscale on the x axis. This does not work, Gnuplot gives the error "x range must be greater than 0 for log scale". I saw examples that used a logscale with negative values on the y axis and tried to do it similar for the x axis, but it seems I can not get it to work. Initially I thought it would be the zero values, but even when I remove them, it does not work.

This is a little example:

```
stats 'stat_data1'
num1=STATS_records
stats 'stat_data2'
num2=STATS_records

set terminal pdf
set output "Cumulative_noise.pdf"
set autoscale yfix
set autoscale xfix
set key bottom right
set xlabel 'Noise in dB'
set ylabel 'Percent'
set xrange [0:110] reverse
set logscale x

set style increment user
set style line 2  lc rgb '#FF0000' lt 1 pt 1 ps 1
set style line 3  lc rgb '#008000' lt 2 pt 2 ps 2
set style line 4  lc rgb '#0000FF' lt 3 pt 3 ps 3

plot 0/0 notitle,\
'stat_data1' u (-$3) : ((100.0/num1)) title 'Node 1' smooth cumulative,\
'stat_data2' u (-$3) : ((100.0/num2)) title 'Node 2' smooth cumulative
```

And here some data. First file:

```
1437818411 -54 -95 85.2 0.0
1437818425 -54 -95 78.0 0.0
1437818440 -71 -95 38.7 0.0
1437818456 -70 -95 51.7 0.0
1437818471 -71 -95 42.0 0.0
```

Second file:

```
1437818545 -50 -95 43.7 100.0
1437818561 -51 -95 52.0 100.0
1437818576 -50 -94 79.4 0.10744142234781584
1437818592 -51 -94 16.6 0.308927509416507
1437818605 -49 -95 85.2 0.04368438558438699
```

I hope somebody has an idea as this would be very convenient. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The "`x range must be greater than 0 for log scale`" error, is because you defined a range for `x` that includes zero (`set xrange [0:110]`). To fix this error you could remove the `set xrange` line or define a non-zero value for xmin (e.g. `set xrange [0.1:110]`).

Comment: That solves it, yes. The minimum value makes it look a bit awkward though, as I can not remove that line, because the reversed is needed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers given in the `xrange` settings are also subject to the actual axis transformations.

Removing the `set xrange [0:110]` fixes the error.

Comment: That does fix it indeed, but then the xrange is nor reversed. It works if I use a positive x value as minimum, although, it does look a bit strange as the lowest value is displayed on the axis.

Comment: What about `set xrange [*:*] reverse `?

Comment: That has the same issue, the x axis is not reversed. My problem is that I need to start from the lowest negative value until zero. It's the other way around with set xrange [*:*] reverse.